# Почему мой код генерирует больше редких значений,нежели меньших

Tags: javascript, node.js, функции

у меня есть функция:

```
randombox(messages) {
    const boxes = ['C', 'U', 'R', 'E', 'L'];
    const chanche = this.utils
      .randomize(0,100)
      .toFixed(0);
    let win;
    switch (true) {
      case chanche <= 10 && chanche > 5:
        win = boxes[0];
        break;
      case chanche <= 5 && chanche > 8:
        win = boxes[1];
        break;
      case chanche <= 8 && chanche > 3:
        win = boxes[2];
        break;
      case chanche <= 3 && chanche > 1:
        win = boxes[3];
        break;
      case chanche <= 1:
        win = boxes[4];
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
    return win;
  }
```

Я прокрутил её 1000 раз и получил кл получения той или иной коробки - результат:

```
C : 57
U : 0
R: 0
E: 21
L: 31
```

Рандомайзер:

```
randomize(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Что я делаю не так,и что можно сделать чтобы оно отвечало своему шансу:

```
C : +- 10
U : +- 5
R: +- 8
E: +- 3
L: +- 1
```

(за 1000 прокруток)

Comment: `case chanche <= 5 && chanche > 8:` — это невозможно.

Comment: У вас пересекаются диапазоны, один невыполнимый вообще (второй) и непонятно, что вы хотите в итоге.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у вас очень замечательные условия

`case chanche <= 10 && chanche > 5`:
От **5** до **10**. То есть только 6,7,8,9,10.

`case chanche <= 5 && chanche > 8`:
Нет таких чисел.

`case chanche <= 8 && chanche > 3`:
От **3** до **8** Зайдёт только если попадется от **3** до **5** если исключить **3** не включено то остаётся только **4**, **5**.

`case chanche <= 3 && chanche > 1`:
Если **3** или **2**.

`case chanche <= 1`:
Если только **0** или **1**.

Ну и подумайте теперь почему.